# Credit card fields do not show after updating

Tags: drupal, payment-processor, contribution-page

I upgraded to CiviCRM 5.0.0 on Friday and our contribution pages do not show the credit card fields any more. I have attempted to re-save the contribution pages and payment processor information. When I try to edit the payment processor, I get the following page. I am not sure what else to try, thank you.

[image]

Comment: I just needed to delete everything in the templates_c folder again. Should I delete question?

Comment: No - do not delete - this is a good question; move your comment into an answer as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I needed to delete everything inside the `sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/` directory;

`rm -R sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/*`

Comment: Does `drush cc civicrm` also do this?

Comment: Not in this case. It's not a matter of caching, but recreating the template files.

Comment: "cv flush" should do the civi equivalent of cc